# How to format DT background *per row*?

Tags: r, dt

I want to use DT's `formatStyle()` to give a colour gradient **per row**.

Given this sample data:

```
library(DT)

data <- round(data.frame(
  x = runif(5, 0, 5),
  y = runif(5, 0, 10), 
  z = runif(5, 0, 20)
), 3)

break_points <- function(x) stats::quantile(x, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
red_shade <- function(x) round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(x) + 1), 0) %>% {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}
```

I can colour the cell backgrounds based on values in the **entire table** using this code:

```
brks <- break_points(data)
clrs <- red_shade(brks)
datatable(data) %>% formatStyle(names(data), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

Or I can colour the cell background based on values **per column** with this code:

```
brks <- apply(data, 2, break_points)
clrs <- apply(brks, 2, red_shade)
dt <- datatable(data)
for(i in colnames(data)){
  dt <- dt %>% formatStyle(i, backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks[,i], clrs[,i]))
}
dt
```

But I'm not sure what's the simplest cleanest solution to do so **per row**, so that in each row the highest value is darkest and the lower value is lightest.

Comment: Not what you asked, Dean, but have you looked at `gt`? I know it provides per-cell formatting with [`gt::data_color`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gt/versions/0.1.0/topics/data_color).

Comment: gt is not mature enough for my needs. It doesn't have any interactivity and isn't great for use in shiny (yet!)

Comment: Interactivity is certainly something I'd like to see added to its feature list. Agreed, just thought I'd mention it. (Wish I had an answer for you for *this* question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a rowCallback:

```
library(DT)

data <- round(data.frame(
  x = runif(10, 0, 5),
  y = runif(10, 0, 10), 
  z = runif(10, 0, 20)
), 3)

break_points <- function(x) stats::quantile(x, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
red_shade <- function(x) round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(x) + 1), 0) %>% {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

brks <- apply(data, 1, break_points)
clrs <- apply(brks, 2, red_shade)

rowCallback <- "function(row, data, displayNum, index){"

for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  rowCallback <- c(
    rowCallback,
    sprintf("var value = data[%d];", i)
  )
  for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
    rowCallback <- c(
      rowCallback, 
      sprintf("if(index === %d){", j-1),
      sprintf("$('td:eq(%d)',row).css('background-color', %s);", 
              i, styleInterval(brks[,j], clrs[,j])),
      "}"
    )
  }
}
rowCallback <- c(rowCallback, "}")

datatable(data, options = list(rowCallback = JS(rowCallback)))
```

[image]

Comment: Merci for the response and the edit. It doesn't look right though, as you pointed out. In the first row, the 6.124 should be much much lighter than 18.101, in the 4th row the 4 should be closer to 3.64 than 19.5, etc.

Comment: @DeanAttali I see one error: `for(i in 1:nrow(data))` should be `for(i in 1:ncol(data))`. But I'm still not convinced.

Comment: Wait, I think I get it.

Comment: @DeanAttali See my updated answer. I think this is correct now.

Comment: ping (and feel free to delete your last comment reply)