# How to customize datatable by row with custom threshold

Tags: r, dt, formattable

This is related to this other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867429/hide-html-code-inside-datatable-edit-when-formatting-the-table-with-formattable/57868569?noredirect=1#comment102162632_57868569).

Currently I'm using this code in order to apply some styling to my table.

I need to color each cell only if the value exceeds the 3rd quantile of the `row`, the problem is that `DT` doesn't seem to allow to work by `row`, just by `column`.

`formattable()` works ok, but I lose some useful proprieties from `DT`, for example the possibility to edit the cell with `editable=T`.

```
library(formattable)
library(DT)

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(AirPassengers, ncol=12, byrow=T))

find_anomaly <- function(x) {
  q3 <- quantile(x, 0.75)
  q3
}

ftable <- formattable(dat, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(row) {
  area(row, col = 1:12) ~ formatter("span", style = x ~ ifelse(x > find_anomaly(x),
                                                               style(
                                                                 display = "block",
                                                                 padding = "0 4px",
                                                                 "border-radius" = "4px",
                                                                 "color" = csscolor("white"),
                                                                 "background-color" = csscolor(
                                                                   gradient(as.numeric(x),"white", "orangered"))),
                                                               NA))
}))

as.datatable(ftable, editable=T)
```

Here you can see that all is good except that the table shows the HTML from `formattable()` once clicked:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the styling generated from `formattable` that works ok with `editable=T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `DT`, applying the `render` option to each column:

```
library(DT)

products <- data.frame(
  X1 = round(runif(5),2),
  X2 = round(runif(5),2),
  X3 = round(runif(5),2),
  X4 = round(runif(5),2),
  X5 = round(runif(5),2),
  X6 = round(runif(5),2),
  X7 = round(runif(5),2),
  X8 = round(runif(5),2),
  X9 = round(runif(5),2),
  X10 = round(runif(5),2)
)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var arr = row.slice();",
  "    arr.sort();",
  "    var per75 =  Math.floor(row.length*.75) - 1;",
  "    var s = data >= arr[per75] ? '<span style=\"padding: 0 4px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: red;\">' + data + '</span>' : data;",
  "    return s;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(products, editable = "cell", rownames = FALSE, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = "_all", render = JS(render))
            )
          )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! This is really good, may I trouble you with a minor problem? See my update, I can't seem to make it work with JS code..sorry if it's OT. Basically my threshold should be given by the interquartile range plus the 3rd quantile.

Comment: @RLave I don't see any error in your code. Maybe the reason is you don't have data higher than the threshold ? Haye your tried with formattable and does it work ?

Comment: I removed the "-1" here `Math.floor(row.length*.75) - 1` and it works like expected.

Comment: Can I ask if it's possible to apply `render` to all columns except the first 2? Maybe by changing the  `targets = "_all"` argument? Currently I'm using `targets = c(1:12)` but I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: @RLave You can do `targets = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`, or `targets = setdiff(1:10, c(1,2))`.**Edit** No sorry, the first column is indexed by `0`. Do `setdiff(0:9, c(0,1))`, rather.